# Async request to firebase inside forEach

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an array like that (generatedArray):

```
[
   {
      ...some data,
      [deals],
      type: 'uo'
   },
   {
      ...some data,
      [deals],
      type: 'pif',
      pifKua: 'some value'
   },
  ...other similar objects
]
```

If type is 'pif' I want to take  snapshot from firebase and put snapshot's value in pifKua field. To do it I have a such function:

```
handleCreateDocs = () => {
    this.generatedArray.forEach( item => {
        console.log('itemtype', item.type);
        if (item.type === 'pif') {
            const stocksRef = firebase.database().ref('clients');
            const kua = stocksRef.orderByChild('shortName').equalTo(item.pifKua);
            kua.once('value').then( snapshot => {
                snapshot.forEach((child) => {
                    Object.assign(item.pifKua, child.val());
                });
            })
        }
    });
    this.setState({
        kuaCheck: true
    }, () => {console.log('kua', this.generatedArray)});
};
```

But after this function this.generatedArray don't changes. In console i can see 'kua', but this.generatedArray still the same witjout any changes. Help me to fix it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only call setState until you have all the data available.  Right now, you are calling it without waiting for any of the queries to complete.  `then` does not cause your code to pause and wait for the result.  It just returns another promise that resolves some time later while your code continues in the forEach loop.

You will need to collect your promises into an an array, and use `Promise.all()` to wait for them to complete.  The general form of your code will be more like this:

```
handleCreateDocs = () => {
    const promises = [];
    this.generatedArray.forEach( item => {
        console.log('itemtype', item.type);
        if (item.type === 'pif') {
            const stocksRef = firebase.database().ref('clients');
            const kua = stocksRef.orderByChild('shortName').equalTo(item.pifKua);
            const promise = kua.once('value').then( snapshot => {
                snapshot.forEach((child) => {
                    Object.assign(item.pifKua, child.val());
                });
            });
            promises.push(promise);
        }
    });

    Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
        console.log("all queries complete");
        this.setState({
            kuaCheck: true
        }, () => {console.log('kua', this.generatedArray)});
    });
};
```